# Saving JQuery Datepicker to Multiple Fields (d/m/y) in Bean

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I'm a super beginner when it comes to Javascript/JQuery/HTML in general, apologies if my question is confusing. I'm trying to update legacy code front-end to use the JQuery datepicker instead of an old drop down menu. The back-end code (that I shouldn't change) uses a string variable for day, month, and year. I'm trying to save the values from datepicker directly into the bean, using the following js:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                document.getElementById('enterAppForm:effectiveDay').value  = date.getDate();  
                document.getElementById('enterAppForm:effectiveMonth').value = date.getMonth() + 1;              
                document.getElementById('enterAppForm:effectiveYear').value =  date.getFullYear();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have the HTML as (inside `<h:form id="enterAppForm">` with a lot of other things):

```
<h:inputText type="text" class="datepicker" id="effectiveDate" name="effectiveDate" />
<h:inputHidden id="effectiveDay" value="#{beanName.effectiveDay}" />
<h:inputHidden id="effectiveMonth" value="#{beanName.effectiveMonth}" />
<h:inputHidden id="effectiveYear" value="#{beanName.effectiveYear}" />
```

If I do something like:

```
day  = date.getDate(),  
month = date.getMonth() + 1,              
year =  date.getFullYear();
alert(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
```

the values do show up correctly. However, the bean shows that it's receiving values of `null` for all 3 variables. I'm sure there's something basic that I'm not understanding, so if anyone can point me towards the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. I've seen examples with PrimeFaces, but this project doesn't use it.

P.S. This step would probably be trivial after I figure out my issue, but a validation js needs to grab `var vEffectiveMonth = document.getElementById('enterAppForm:effectiveMonth');` for it to work. It shouldn't matter it's a hidden field, right? It was linked to the old drop down menu before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding right you are using this code:

```
document.getElementById('enterAppForm:effectiveDay').value  = date.getDate();  
document.getElementById('enterAppForm:effectiveMonth').value = date.getMonth() + 1;              
document.getElementById('enterAppForm:effectiveYear').value =  date.getFullYear();
```

To set the value on these HTML elements:

```
<h:inputHidden id="effectiveDay" value="#{beanName.effectiveDay}" />
<h:inputHidden id="effectiveMonth" value="#{beanName.effectiveMonth}" />
<h:inputHidden id="effectiveYear" value="#{beanName.effectiveYear}" />
```

If so, your IDs don't match up. Since you are already using jQuery, it will be easier and you won't have to worry about browser comparability if you simply did this:

```
$("#effectiveDay").val(data.getDate());
$("#effectiveMonth").val(date.getMonth() + 1);
$("#effectiveYear").val(data.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at datpicker api you can see [OnSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) has a inst parameter. It contains the date you selected.

```
var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
```

is useless. Here you can see an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/1twc688r/2/) with HTML/JQuery. It shouldn't be so different

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I was missing. However, when I try to use this method, the fields still won't populate when I change the date. What might be some common reasons? There aren't any errors when I run the code, so I'm lost as to where to start looking.

Comment: As you can see in the example, you can do that. I don't know what could be the reason, but i think you should follow @Amir suggestion, using JQuery syntax to select your elements. You can try to use console.log() function to debug your code.